# How fetch a json query response from an api in python using requests library?

Tags: python, jquery, json, api, python-requests

I want to pass a json query as an argument in the requests.get method in python and get the query based response from the url.

```
query_params = {
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "user_id"
    }
  },
  "size":10000
}

headers = {"X-API-Key": api_key, "Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.post(url, params=json.dumps(query_params), headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

Here the output is not based on the query parameters, it is the normal response we get even if we don't pass the query.

I tried the get method

```
response = requests.get(url, params=query_params, headers=headers)
```

Both gave me a response that is not based on the passed query. I have also tried the same query in postman that gives me the correct response. I ensured that the headers are the same in both postman and in my script. The header format is X-API-Key:.

What is the correct way to pass a query request in the requests library to get a query based response?

Comment: Have you tried adding **User-Agent** to your headers? It might help for some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a JSON query as an argument in the `requests.get()` method in Python, you need to use the `json` parameter instead of the params parameter. The params parameter is used to pass query parameters in the URL, while the `json` parameter is used to send JSON data in the request body.

```
import requests
import json

query_params = {
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "user_id"
    }
  },
  "size": 10000
}

headers = {"X-API-Key": api_key, "Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.get(url, json=query_params, headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use json instead of params

```
response = requests.post(url, json=query_params, headers=headers)
```

This worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate python code from your postman request.
I think it will solve your problem, also it will give you understanding of what you was doing wrong.

Here check this out [Postman: Generating client code](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/)